# Can access website but images, css stylesheets and javascript files do not download

Tags: tomcat, files, resources, css

i have this problem, not sure about the source of it, Basically the title describes the issue, I can access the webpage and see the html structure, but no resources are being donwloaded nor I have access to them using the browser that means, no javascript, no css styles and no images., any solutions?, Im using tomcat by the way.

---

**EDIT 1**

If I access the tomcat manager from within the server it also blocks the images.
I'm running on windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: which HTTP status code do you get as response?

Comment: Have you tried a debugging proxy, such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)?

Comment: I get `Error 404` like if the files are not there, but the fact is that they are there. I can use the webpage and access the servlets but not Stylesheets, js files or images.

Comment: No, I haven't tried the debugging proxy

Comment: Sounds like a path problem to me. Are your HREFs relative or explicit? If they're relative, are the file in the right place relative to the HTML file that's loading them?

Comment: they're relative (they don't have a forward slash), also when i try to access it the URL points to the correct folder

Comment: Check file permissions, make sure they are readable files?

Comment: The app folder is marked as read'only..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, issue solved, it appears that reinstalling tomcat using the installer fixed the issue., thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the default servlet (responsible for serving static files) configuration (in `conf/web.xml`)?

Comment: I don't thinks so, but I'm not so sure, in case I did that what configuration setting would be responsible of that?